# MS SQL Server Incremental(differential) backup interrupted due to Full backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, msdb

I have a manual full backup happening every night, post which I am taking differential backup after every hour but after  three to four differential backups a full backup happened through third party automated backup happen, which is not in my control.

Can any please suggest the best approach to be followed if I don't want to stop the automated backup taken by third party and differential backup not to be failed because of this?.

Comment: Does the third party app have an option to change the backup to `COPY-ONLY` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't control if the backup happens, could you ask the third party to change how the backup is taken? Using the `COPY_ONLY` option stops backups from interrupting other backup sequences, so if they add that to their process it will stop interfering with your's. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191495(v=sql.120).aspx for more info.

That is the only option that doesn't require an extra copy of the database. Other than that you could maintain a replica and have the 3rd party take their backups from there (or take your backups from there).

Comment: Thank you David for the quick response. I tried testing this approach and observed that I would have to change the this COPY ONLY option only in 3rd party tool. As when I manually tries to take the backup and differential backup with COPY ONLY I am not able to restore them back on my database. It says LSN chain breaks.